# Prove that if $f$ is convex and upper bounded, it must be constant.

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a convex, upper bounded function. Prove $f$ is constant.

I know that this question was asked already. But I didn't understand how it was solved. (By the graph, I know there must be concave parts, which is contradictory.). How do I get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f(x)<M$ for all $x$. Consider two points $x_1,x_2$. If $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$, then the line $\ell$ through $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ intersects the line $y=M$. Since $f(x)$ must lie on or above $\ell$ for all $x\notin[x_1,x_2]$, this is not possible.

Comment: Just the kind of proof I was looking for, thanks. :)

Comment: were*? 
(Not my mother language)